# How to impersonate AD user in web service?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, servicestack

I want my web service (using servicestack, if that matters) to be able to authenticate against the AD, and then switch identity to that user.

I see quite a few tutorials on how to authenticate against active directory, but don't see anything related to actual impersonation.

Basically I want something along those lines:

```
DirectoryEntry user = // authenticate against AD
// Switch current user identity 
// Do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a user token generated by [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Best example here (read the full answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/939250).